# Installing OpenCV in Ubuntu without internet connection

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu, installation

I had a question about installing OpenCV on a linux machine.

I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.11 (from [here](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)) on a Ubuntu linux machine that doesn't have internet. It's on its own stand alone network and won't be connected to the internet at all. I was wondering, how do I install OpenCV (for python) given the current conditions? Any documentation online points to using sudo apt-get or other methods that use the internet to install.

Right now I have installed Anaconda on the machine that gave me most of the dependencies that are required, but if I need to install any other dependencies, I can easily download the source code (and run like setup.py to install it), burn it on a disk and install it.

Comment: Moderators/Users don't downvote the question without pointing to duplicates if there are any. I think this is a legitimate question.

Comment: you'll need to find a way , to update your numpy, too

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded the OpenCV source code, building OpenCV is fairly straightforward.  You will only need the internet if you have any unmet dependencies (which it sounds like you're able to take care of).

```
cd opencv-source-code
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
sudo make install
```

This may take a while so have patience.  The full instructions along with all the required dependencies can be found here: [Linux installation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with casper (but cannot comment). It is possible that even when building the code yourself you'll need internet connection to download `ippicv` (which happens automatically when running `cmake`). The instructions how to circumvent it are [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/40425/opencv-build-fails-because-i-cannot-download-icv-on-our-build-farm/).